# Determining median values with nested IF and AND array formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create two similar array formulas:

One is to determine the median value of the cells in a column (B), but only if there are both corresponding blank values in column J, and there are numeric values in column D. (D and J are in separate sheets.)

The other formula is the do the same thing, except it will only determine the median for the cells in B for which the corresponding cells in column J are not blank.

I should note I am making sure to enter them in with command-shift-enter, since they are array formulas. However, it's coming out to zero for both of them. I've tried for a long time and can't figure out why. I'm new to Excel formulas, so please let me know if I should clarify my question.

First formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(

 AND('Raw Data'!$J$3:'Raw Data'!$J$999="", ISNUMBER('Raw Data'!$D$3:'Raw Data'!$D$999)),

 B$6:B$1002))
```

Second formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(

 AND(NOT(ISBLANK('Raw Data'!$J$3:'Raw Data'!$J$999)), ISNUMBER('Raw Data'!$D$3:'Raw Data'!$D$999)),

 B$6:B$1002))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array equivalent of `AND` is multiplication `*`:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(('Raw Data'!$J$3:$J$999="")*
            ISNUMBER('Raw Data'!$D$3:$D$999),
            B$6:B$1002)
       )
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

For second formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(NOT(ISBLANK('Raw Data'!$J$3:$J$999))*
           ISNUMBER('Raw Data'!$D$3:$D$999),
           B$6:B$1002)
       )
```

also with array entry.

---

**Explanation why `AND` not working.**

What you expect is that `AND({TRUE,FALSE,FALSE},{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE})` returns `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}`.

However, `AND` takes *array* of boolean values and returns *single* boolean value - which indicates whether *all* values are `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

So, `AND({TRUE,FALSE,FALSE},{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE})` returns `FALSE` because not all values are `TRUE`.

But, multiplication  `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}*{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}` works exactly as you need it - it returns `{TRUE*TRUE,FALSE*TRUE,FALSE*FALSE} = {TRUE, FALSE, FALSE}`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for your thorough answer and explanation — this is incredibly helpful.