# MS Excel - Find Missing Date values between two dates in a column full of dates

Tags: database, date, excel-formula

I have a master list of SKUs in one table set as a column with a different SKU listed in each row.

I have another table with a daily snapshot of items which I have in stock between 7/1/17 and 7/31/17 in each row. The table shows the item SKU in one column, the warehouse where there is quantity in another column, and the quantity available within that warehouse in another column. There can be multiple occurrences of a SKU on one date if there are quantity in multiple warehouses. The table only lists SKUs on occurrences where there is quantity within a warehouse. If a SKU has no quantity within any of the warehouses on a date, it will not be listed in the table corresponding with that date.

In my table with the master list of SKUs I want to create a column that will show the the number of days within a range of dates (7/1/17 to 7/8/17) in which there were no quantity of the SKU being referenced available in any warehouse.

To show a more precise idea of what it is I am trying to do, I have posted a youtube video here: http://youtu.be/6CWLN6wzaWQ?hd=1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following URLs - I feel partially similar cases are discussed and resolved over there.

It will surely give you some lead to further work on.

[How to return multiple values between two dates in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099974/how-to-return-multiple-values-between-two-dates-in-excel)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/finding-missing-dates-in-column/8c49800a-6997-4585-b1f4-abdeaa64e718